# Why isn't this cd command working in batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

First, some context for the question. I've written a small script that automates most of a tedious process surrounding updating an application I wrote. Each time I reinstall the application, it creates a folder with a name that's an alphanumeric jumble that is different with each install. In my script, I'm trying to `cd` into this folder. Since it changes every time, I can't just hardcode it.

This is the command I use. It works every single time when I put it into the command line, but only works half the time running from my .bat. When it doesn't work, it just says "the system cannot find the path specified." I'm assuming the issue has to do with the wildcard there at the end, but since it works when I put it directly into CMD, I can't figure out what the problem is.

`cd "[filepath]\ED2...tion_*"`

Why isn't it working and how can I make it work? Thanks.

Comment: If `[filepath]` is on another drive, _(i.e. one which isn't on the same drive as the current working directory at the time the command is run)_, you must use `CD /D "[filepath]\ED2…tion_*"`.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the wildcard expression will expand to exactly one name?

Comment: It's not on another drive. I didn't include the path because it's a long alphabet soup, but everything's in C:\Users\etc.

Comment: In every tests, it always expanded to just one name. Even if it didn't, I'd expect the same behavior as when you do tab for autocomplete but there's multiple options.

Comment: Assuming that a path '*' would produce the same result as an autocomplete tab first result does not seem a robust mechanism. I would be reluctant to count on code that assumed such a situation.

Comment: Granted. However, the situation is such that it is good enough for what I'm doing, and nothing is hurt if it goes wrong. I just need to be able to make the line actually execute correctly.

Comment: Does it work any better for you if you use a for loop? e.g. `For /D %%G In ("[filepath]\ED2...tion_*") Do @CD /D "%%G"`. If a directory doesn't exist, nothing will happen, not even an error message!